# What OCR options exist beyond Tesseract?

Tags: php, python, ruby, ocr, tesseract

I've used Tesseract a bit and it's results leave much to be desired.  I'm currently detecting very small images (35x15, without border, but have tried adding one with imagemagick with no ocr advantage); they range from 2 chars to 5 and are a pretty reliable font, however the characters are variable enough that simply using an image size checksum or such is not going to work.

**What options exist for OCR besides sticking with Tesseract or doing a complete custom training of it?**  Also, it would be VERY helpful if this were compatible with Heroku style hosting (at least where I can compile the bins and shove them over).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have successfully used [GOCR](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/) in the past for small image OCR. I would say accuracy was around 85%, after getting the grayscale options set properly, on fairly regular fonts. It fails miserably when the fonts get complicated and has trouble with multiline layouts.

Also have a look at [Ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/), which is maintained by Google. Its related to Tesseract, but from what I understand, its OCR engine is different. With just the default models included, it achieves near 99% accuracy on high-quality images, handles layout pretty well and provides HTML output with information concerning formatting and lines.  However, in my experience, its accuracy is *very* low when the image quality is not good enough. That being said, training is relatively simple and you might want to give it a try.

Both of them are easily callable from the command line. GOCR usage is very straightforward; just type `gocr -h` and you should have all the information you need. Ocropus is a bit more tricky; here's a usage example, in Ruby:

```
require 'fileutils'
tmp = 'directory'
file = 'file.png'

`ocropus book2pages #{tmp}/out #{file}`
`ocropus pages2lines #{tmp}/out`
`ocropus lines2fsts #{tmp}/out`
`ocropus buildhtml #{tmp}/out > #{tmp}/output.html`

text = File.read("#{tmp}/output.html")
FileUtils.rm_rf(tmp)
```

Comment: Very interesting!  Thanks a bunch.  I would be particularly interested in training.  I can limit the vocabulary to about 50 "words" if vocabulary training or limiting is possible so as to give it a defined set of boundaries.

Comment: I recommend you have a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6qKa3St9S8), which gives a solid explanation of how to train Ocropus. Training for GOCR remains a mystery to me; I am not even sure it is possible, and the docs are unhelpful.

Comment: For `ocropus`, did you use the older codebase that hasn't been updated for a few years or checkout from the repo and compile the newer updates in the works?

Comment: I used `port install` - not sure how old the port definitions are/were when I installed it. I don't know if it is still the case, but for a long time this was the only way to get it to compile on Mac OS X without hours of burning in dependency hell. But I'd definitely try compiling from source, if you can get it to work.

Comment: I'm considering working on a homebrew recipe, however it seems a bit involved.  The new source release from just the past few days has an install script, but it needs some help for mac os x. `http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/source/list` and `http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/wiki/InstallTranscript` may prove some useful references.

Comment: I'm sure that would be welcome by many - its definitely a great tool, and should be made more accessible IMO.

Comment: We had some discussion about it on IRC, however it appears no one is really willing to tackle a head based formula for it.  Any idea of how close we are to a full release of the .5?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

We use OCR XTR Lite from Vividata at my office. It uses the ScanSoft engine and is very accurate but isn't a free solution. Currently it is being scripted from bash and I process from 75,000 to 150,000 pages a day with it. Accuracy is almost perfect and it auto-rotates the images to determine the OCR orientation.